# What's the minimum number of information required to solve a triangle?

Tags: triangles

In school, I was always taught that given 3 pieces information with at least the length of one side, it was possible to determine all the measures of a triangle.

However, I recently stumbled on the following problem, to which I found two solutions:

> Find all the measures of the triangle that has a $64\unicode{xB0}$ angle opposed to a $48\ cm$ side and adjacent to a $50\ cm$ side.

[**First solution**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCR9W.png) -> The angles measure $64\unicode{xB0}$, $46.57\unicode{xB0}$ and $69.43\unicode{xB0}$

[**Second solution**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWhxX.png) -> The angles measure $64\unicode{xB0}$, $5.43\unicode{xB0}$ and $110.57\unicode{xB0}$

So, what's the real minimum number of pieces of information to solve a triangle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knowing three sides, two angles and a side, or two sides adjacent to a given angle always give enough information to determine a triangle uniquely, by the SSS, ASA (and AAS), and SAS laws, respectively. Knowing two sides and an angle not between those two sides, or SSA, is a special case in the sense that there may be either $1$,$2$, or no triangles at all satisfying a given choice of lengths for two sides and an angle. In particular there will exist a unique triangle satisfying a SSA choice if the given side opposite to the angle is longer than the side adjacent to the angle.

Answer (score 3):

[Solution of triangles Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_triangles)

The case you have is SSA which is not uniquely specified.